# Difference between heading inside section or before it in HTML5

Tags: html, semantics, html-heading

In HTML5, what is the difference between a `section` with a `h`eading as child element and a `section` which is the next sibling of a `h`eading element? Does the same difference hold for `div` elements instead of `section`?

```
<section>
<h1>First section</h1>
<!-- other content -->
</section>

<!-- vs. -->

<h1>Second section</h1>
<section>
<!-- other content -->
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest and most important difference is how outlining algorithms will parse the html page. Since heading elements offer no way to mark the end of the section they relate to; they cannot nest either. `<section>` elements can be nested, and thus allow to properly markup a document's outline.

[smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/18/the-importance-of-sections/) has a detailed explanation of how it works and how it can and should be used, they also provide examples and common pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

The answers will highly depend upon logical view.

```
<section>
  <h1>....</h1>
</section>
```

On the above case `<h1>` denotes the heading of the section. Now lets look at another example:

```
<div id="info">
    <h1>Sections:</h1>
    <section>
       <h1> Section: 1</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
       <h2> Section: 2</h2>
    </section>
</div>
```

This the  defines a major portion of a page called `sections`, where as the heading inside each heading, only tend to emphasis the contains within the section i.e of a particular type of section like `section 1`.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In the first, the h1 is a heading for the content of that section while, in the second, it's a heading for all the content below the h1 which may include more than one section.

The biggest difference between the two is that the section, in the second example, can contain an additional its own h1 element.